# Malformed Unicode code sequence in the field

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am trying browser uploads to my s3 bucket using POST form. I am using [eddturtle/direct-upload](https://github.com/eddturtle/direct-upload) to generate the policy and signature. This is my code:

```
$upload = new Signature(
            self::S3_KEY,
            self::S3_SECRET,
            self::S3_BUCKET,
            self::S3_REGION
        );
```

And generating the html using `$upload->getFormInputsAsHtml()` method. Which is generating an html like this

```
<form action="//s3.amazonaws.com/bucket" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read">
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_status" value="201">
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNy0wMi0xNVQxMzowNDozOFoiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJ0YWdmaSJ9LHsiYWNsIjoicHJpdmF0ZSJ9LFsic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCIka2V5IiwiIl0sWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsIiRDb250ZW50LVR5cGUiLCIiXSxbImNvbnRlbnQtbGVuZ3RoLXJhbmdlIiwwLDUyNDI4ODAwMF0seyJzdWNjNzX2FjdGlvbl9zdGF0dXMiOiIyMDEifSx7IngtYW16LWNyZWRlbnRpYWwiOiJBS0lBSkhGS0hKMklLNjZTVFA0QVwvMjAxNzAyMTVcL3VzLWVhc3QtMVwvczNcL2F3czRfcmVxdWVzdCJ9LHsieC1hbXotYWxnb3JpdGhtIjoiQVdTNC1ITUFDLVNIQTI1NiJ9LHsieC1hbXotZGF0ZSI6IjIwMTcwMjE1VDA3MDQzOFoifV19">
    <input type="hidden" name="X-amz-credential" value="AKIAJHFKHJ2IK66STP4A/20170215/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request">
    <input type="hidden" name="X-amz-algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256">
    <input type="hidden" name="X-amz-date" value="20170215T070438Z">
    <input type="hidden" name="X-amz-signature" value="e9d30613e4fcab8fec3fe75c4ce2969bb6497d83af7cca7f9ea6a1c0738844c5">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}">
</form>
```

But after submitting the form I am getting this error from s3

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
    <Message>Malformed Unicode code sequence in the field.</Message>
    <ArgumentName>formField</ArgumentName>
    <RequestId>46E52494FC98ED76</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        Qk/g94sJSfVicIxPb3oFN0nO1EVCvxy8YzBQjRKyKpATZZmX1VjlDK+zWfvidhZl5vuemZyuKg0=
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

Sample request payload

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVGEGWkAW5d70u2rp Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="shop-small.png" Content-Type:
> image/png
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVGEGWkAW5d70u2rp Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVGEGWkAW5d70u2rp Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acl"
>
> private
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVGEGWkAW5d70u2rp Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"
>
> 201
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVGEGWkAW5d70u2rp Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"
>
> 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
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVGEGWkAW5d70u2rp Content-Disposition: form-data; name="X-amz-credential"
>
> AKIAJHFKHJ2IK66STP4A/20170215/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVGEGWkAW5d70u2rp Content-Disposition: form-data; name="X-amz-algorithm"
>
> AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVGEGWkAW5d70u2rp Content-Disposition: form-data; name="X-amz-date"
>
> 20170215T131355Z
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVGEGWkAW5d70u2rp Content-Disposition: form-data; name="X-amz-signature"
>
> 1c28fb88fc0b1317df11b7f566fe39eaac9b8cba012b8fef80448e93767f2677
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVGEGWkAW5d70u2rp Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"
>
> testfile
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryVGEGWkAW5d70u2rp--

I don't know what the issue is and how to fix it. Every example I have gone  through is using similar process. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not see an obvious error, but one possibility is that this error is occurring after `${filename}` is expanded.  Try temporarily replacing this, in the form, with a static value, like `testfile`, or upload a file with only ascii characters in its name, just as a test.

Comment: no luck.. @Michael-sqlbot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it fixed. Though I still don't know what was causing the issue. Instead of using `$upload->getFormInputsAsHtml();`  to get the form content, I used `$s3Policy = $upload->getFormInputs();` to get the policy and individually assigning to pre-written html.

```
<form :action="aws_url" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" :value="s3Policy.content_type" />
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" :value="s3Policy.acl" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_status" :value="s3Policy.success_action_status" />
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" :value="s3Policy.policy" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-amz-credential" :value="s3Policy.credential" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-amz-algorithm" :value="s3Policy.algorithm" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-amz-date" :value="s3Policy.date" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-amz-signature" :value="s3Policy.signature" />
    <input type="hidden" name="key" :value="s3Policy.key" />
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">

</form>
```

May be this was caused by `vuejs` on my frontend but the html looked fine in dev console.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your "policy" value and pasted it on https://www.base64decode.org

The default encoding is UTF-8.

It failed to decode.

When I changed it to ASCII, the result was partially ok.

> {"expiration":"2017-02-15T13:04:38Z","conditions":[{"bucket":"tagfi"},{"acl":"private"},["starts-with","$key",""],["starts-with","$Content-Type",""],["content-length-range",0,524288000],{"succ757F7FGW2###''7&VFVF#$d$ce5ED#s#UW2V7B35w3E&WVW7B''v&F#$u3B24#Sb''FFR###s#UCsC3'

It looks like "success" may have a different "e".

Try posting you plain text policy on https://www.base64encode.org and use that encoded value.

Or reply it here so I can take a look.

Hope this helps

Comment: thats because i deleted couple of characters

Comment: If you could give me the full base64 encoded value, I would be more than happy to help you isolate the problem.

Comment: `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`

Answer (score 0):

I decoded your base64 content
It looks like you have extra characters on your "credential" field. 
Looks like
AKIAJHFKHJ2IK66STP4A\/20170215\/us-east-1\/s3\/aws4_request

You will need to change it to
AKIAJHFKHJ2IK66STP4A/20170215/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request

Comment: well, same error.. And I guess those back slashes are being added while decoding as escaping the forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, there was an additional field that was causing this. So just removing it resolved it

```
key: 23/26da4cfd-dfd1-4d8d-a69b-4de51ad6b0b0.png
Content-Type: image/png
bucket: user-data
X-Amz-Algorithm: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
X-Amz-Credential: AKIO/1/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
X-Amz-Date: 
20230129T022521Z
Policy: eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAyMy0wMS0y
X-Amz-Signature: 5ceb01fc3b135ca1ec6ef42de
file: (binary)
image: (binary) <---- This field was the issue
```